# I am getting this invalid locale name :" en_IN" error while making a copy of postgresql database on my local system?

Tags: postgresql, locale

This code:

```
CREATE DATABASE fusionlab WITH
   TEMPLATE = template0
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   LOCALE = 'en_IN';
```

causes this error:

```
psql:C:/Intel/fusionlab_db.sql:23: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_IN"
psql:C:/Intel/fusionlab_db.sql:26: error: \connect: FATAL:  database "fusionlab" does not exist
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This needs more information: 1) What is happening at  or around line 23 of fusionlab_db.sql that causes the error? 2) Where did the database originate from? What are the locale settings there? 3) Where is the database being built, e.g what are the locale settings?

Comment: database originate from an erp site of institute and database was being built on pc as localserver

Comment: Please include that information as an update to your question. You have not mentioned what the `locale` is set to in the two environments, though the error would indicate that the local server either does not have the `en_IN` locale or the database cluster that the database is being created in has not been created with that locale.

Answer (score 0):

That means that your operating system doesn't have the locale `en_IN` configured.

If it is a Unix-like system, run this from the command line:

```
locale -a
```

That will give you a list of available locales.